# XFCE/X11: Keyboard layout changes overnight, special symbols can not be entered

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, xfce, dell-latitude

A very weird problem

- After work, I lock my screen and go home
- The morning after, my keyboard layout has changed from de_CH to en_US
- At random times, my urxvt-tabbed windows don't accept special chars anymore (`|`,`#` etc.)

Some information about the system:

- Dell Latitude E6230, external USB Keyboard
- Arch Linux 64bit, last update 1 week ago
- XFCE 4

Keyboard layout:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     ch
variant:    legacy
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+ch(legacy)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ch(legacy)+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug in XFCE. According to [bug 10152](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10152), this should be fixed in version 0.5.6 of Xfce4-xkb-plugin.